# Import VPC config from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I can't import the existing VPC config from Terraform.

The original code, that created this network was:

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "~> v2.66"

  name = "my-vpc"
  cidr = var.vpc_cidr

  azs              = var.availability_zones
  private_subnets  = var.vpc_private_subnets
  public_subnets   = var.vpc_public_subnets
  database_subnets = var.vpc_database_subnets
  redshift_subnets = var.vpc_redshift_subnets

  enable_nat_gateway     = true
  enable_vpn_gateway     = true
  enable_public_redshift = true

  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = merge(
    tomap({
      "kubernetes.io/cluster/my-production-cluster-" = "shared"
      "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb"              = ""
      "kubernetes.io/role/elb"                       = ""
  }))
  public_subnet_tags  = merge(tomap({ "kubernetes.io/role/elb" = "1" }))
  private_subnet_tags = merge(tomap({ "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb" = "1" }))
}
```

Network variables consist of two subnets per each.

Now I have to create a new terraform config for this module and bind it with the existing VPC.
After planning Terraform proposes me to re-create all VPC-related infrastructure.

So, I'm trying to import it like that:

```
terraform import module.vpc.aws_vpc.this vpc-XXXXX
```

That pass without errors, bit all rest commands give me a same picture:

```
$ terraform import module.vpc.aws_vpn_gateway.this igw-XXX
module.vpc.aws_vpn_gateway.this: Importing from ID "igw-XXX"...
module.vpc.aws_vpn_gateway.this: Import prepared!
  Prepared aws_vpn_gateway for import
module.vpc.aws_vpn_gateway.this: Refreshing state... [id=igw-XXX]

Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
│ 
│ While attempting to import an existing object to "module.vpc.aws_vpn_gateway.this", the provider detected that no object exists with the given id. Only pre-existing objects can be imported; check that the id is correct and that it is associated with the provider's
│ configured region or endpoint, or use "terraform apply" to create a new remote object for this resource.
```

or

```
$ terraform import module.vpc.aws_db_subnet_group.database my-production-vpc-db-us-east-2a
module.vpc.aws_db_subnet_group.database: Importing from ID "my-production-vpc-db-us-east-2a"...
module.vpc.aws_db_subnet_group.database: Import prepared!
  Prepared aws_db_subnet_group for import
module.vpc.aws_db_subnet_group.database: Refreshing state... [id=my-production-vpc-db-us-east-2a]

Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
│ 
│ While attempting to import an existing object to "module.vpc.aws_db_subnet_group.database", the provider detected that no object exists with the given id. Only pre-existing objects can be imported; check that the id is correct and that it is associated with the
│ provider's configured region or endpoint, or use "terraform apply" to create a new remote object for this resource.
```

I've tried other ways to type resource names like that:

```
terraform import module.vpc.aws_vpn_gateway.this[0] igw-XXX
terraform import module.vpc.aws_vpn_gateway.this[\"0\"] igw-XXX
terraform import 'module.vpc.aws_vpn_gateway.this[0]' igw-XXX

terraform import module.vpc.aws_db_subnet_group.database[0] my-production-vpc-db-us-east-2a
terraform import module.vpc.aws_db_subnet_group.database[\"0\"] my-production-vpc-db-us-east-2a
terraform import 'module.vpc.aws_db_subnet_group.database[0]' my-production-vpc-db-us-east-2a
```

all without luck.

Here is the fragment of terraform plan:

```
 # module.vpc.aws_db_subnet_group.database[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "database" {
      + arn         = (known after apply)
      + description = "Database subnet group for adboost-production-vpc"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + name        = "my-vpc"
      + name_prefix = (known after apply)
      + subnet_ids  = (known after apply)
      + tags        = {
          + "Name"                                                  = "my-vpc"
          + "kubernetes.io/cluster/my-production-cluster-"          = "shared"    
          + "kubernetes.io/role/elb"                                = ""
          + "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb"                       = ""
        }
      + tags_all    = {
          + "Name"                                                  = "my-vpc"
          + "kubernetes.io/cluster/my-production-cluster-"          = "shared"    
          + "kubernetes.io/role/elb"                                = (known after apply)
          + "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb"                       = (known after apply)
        }
    }

...

 # module.vpc.aws_vpn_gateway.this[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_vpn_gateway" "this" {
      + amazon_side_asn = "64512"
      + arn             = (known after apply)
      + id              = (known after apply)
      + tags            = {
          + "Name"                                                  = "my-vpc"
          + "kubernetes.io/cluster/my-production-cluster-"          = "shared"    
          + "kubernetes.io/role/elb"                                = ""
          + "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb"                       = ""
        }
      + tags_all        = {
          + "Name"                                                  = "my-vpc"
          + "kubernetes.io/cluster/my-production-cluster-"          = "shared"    
          + "kubernetes.io/role/elb"                                = (known after apply)
          + "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb"                       = (known after apply)
        }
      + vpc_id          = "vpc-XXX"
    }
```

The other parts of the VPC module also have the same errors on import

Answer (score 0):

A VPN Gateway and an Internet Gateway are not the same things, which explains why that resource is failing to import.

As per [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_subnet_group), you should specify the "name" of the DB Subnet Group when you import it. So what is the name of the existing DB Subnet Group? Is it "my-production-vpc-db-us-east-2a" like you are trying in the import command, or is it "my-vpc" like you have configured in the Terraform file?

Comment: > So what is the name of the existing DB Subnet Group? 
I have 2 subnet groups: my-production-vpc-db-us-east-2a and my-production-vpc-db-us-east-2b.  And I'm trying to use one of them (found in AWS console) in import command.

Note, that Terraform config was migrated from Terraform 0.14 to Terraform 1.0, and plugins were updated, so I'm not sure the old config looks EXACTLY the same, but I do remember, that I don't set names for DB Subnet Groups explicitly.